# Counterpart of oracle syntax in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

So I have an oracle syntax that goes by:

```
CREATE TABLE "tb_test" (
"id" NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_test PRIMARY KEY);
```

I am trying to convert Oracle syntax to MySQL.
Is it correct to say that the MySQL counterpart is:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Also how does the (pk_test) from Oracle fit into the MySQL? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, the primary key of a table is named PRIMARY.

If MySQL accepts syntax for name of the primary key constraint, the supplied name is "accepted" as valid syntax, and then ignored and discarded.

Oracle NUMBER datatype has a much larger range of values than MySQL INT.